# Move around between StreetView Panos with full controls

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I'm attempting to learn with limited time.

I've paid somebody to do this work for me, so it's not that I won't pay experts. However, I also want to learn. I asked for code with excellent commenting and got, well, not what I needed.

I know this is probably extremely basic, but I'm missing it and I've tried for a while.

I want to move to a new pano from an old pano in streetview. The way I've figured out how to do it only sets the panoID, it doesn't change the links or anything else. So, quite clearly, I'm doing it wrong.

How do you load pano then move to the next linked pano using the available data in the first pano?

This is how far I got: 
http://jsfiddle.net/sxf7Y/5/

This is what it looks like when somebody that knows how does it:
http://www.crazywithfreedom.com/forCarlos/Carlos/

I've looked at the code, but it is too complex for me to decipher since it builds itself too.

In mine the pano rotates to the link I want (2nd link) and then changes pano. However, the controls from the old pano remain on screen (and of course don't work since those panos aren't available from here). I don't want to just change the picture, I want to change to the new pano's location.

Thanks for any help.

Highlighted bits

```
//The original location
var cafeAmore = new google.maps.LatLng(53.549634, -113.506854);
//...options, there are more specified in the fiddle
var panoramaOptions = {position: cafeAmore,
    addressControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER
    },
    zoomControl: false,
    linksControl: true,
    panControl: false,
    fov: cafeAmorePov[3], //heading, pitch, zoom, fov (degrees of view)
    pov: {
        heading: cafeAmorePov[0], //heading, pitch, zoom, fov (degrees of view)
        pitch: cafeAmorePov[1]
    },
    zoom: cafeAmorePov[2] //heading, pitch, zoom, fov (degrees of view)
};
//call the initial 'canvas' 
var cafe = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
cafeAmoreDiv,
panoramaOptions);
//identify links and attempt to move to a pano
    var links = cafe.getLinks();
    var linkToMoveToHeading = links[1].heading;
    if ((cafeAmorePov[0] > linkToMoveToHeading) && (autoPano = true)) {
        newPanoId = links[1].pano;
        cafe.setPano(newPanoId);
```